# setting up event pattern in cloud watch event rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am having a problem with my terraform. my lambda is expecting a specific format of message from CloudWatch event rule

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "send_hello" {
    name = "say-hi"
    schedule_expression = "cron(0/5 * * * *)"
    is_enabled = true
    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
    {
    "who": "Peter",
    "message_part_1": "hello",
    "message_part_2": "this is the world"
 }
PATTERN
}
```

I am getting

```
"who" must be an object or array
```

my lambda needs to receive an event of

```
{
   "who": "Peter",
   "message_part_1": "hello",
   "message_part_2": "this is the world"
}
```

how should I format my event pattern?

ADDITIONAL:
the following changes do create the resource, but there is no "who" or "message" in the event when the rule calls lambda

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "send_hello" {
    name = "say-hi"
    schedule_expression = "cron(0/5 * * * *)"
    is_enabled = true
    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
    {
    "who": ["Peter"],
    "message_part_1": ["hello"],
    "message_part_2": ["this is the world"]
 }
PATTERN
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `send_hello` works on schedule, thus `event_pattern` does not apply. If you want to pass something to your lambda on schedule, you have to specify [input_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#input_template) of your `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` instead:

> Template to customize data sent to the target. Must be valid JSON.

Comment: Marcin can you explain how we can access that input from Go lambda i am not getting that input here in lambda