# Can we combine event pattern and scheduling exp in CloudWatch Event rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to use custom event_pattern to be used in my lambda whenever event rule triggers my lambda
but the issue is i heard somewhere we cannot combine event pattern and scheduling at the same time
here my terraform code

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "event_lambda_trigger" {
  name        = "event_lambda_trigger"
  description = "Trigger Lambda function daily for cloud watch event"
  schedule_expression = "cron(*/5 * * * ? *)" # This schedules the event to run daily at midnight UTC
  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source = ["aws.events"],
    detail = {
      eventName: ["my-custom-event"],
    },
  })
}
```

Here is my Go lambda handler

```golang
func handler(event events.CloudWatchEvent) (string, error) {
  // Handle CloudWatch Event (event logs) here
  // Access event.Detail and other properties as needed
  fmt.Printf(string(event.Detail))
  return fmt.Sprint("event", string(event.Source)), nil
}
```

I want to get the event pattern also in the form of Detail as we can get that using detail

I tried event pattern and scheduling to work with combination but event trigger, event pattern has {} empty json object but i am passing it in detail of terraform block.

Update: According to the aws doc we cannot use scheduling with event pattern so in that case, I am using the input parameter in aws_cloudwatch_event_target but still didn't get data in lambda here is the link for the solved issue: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956840/setting-up-event-pattern-in-cloud-watch-event-rule)

Comment: This wouldn't make any sense. Events are triggered jn real-time by a change in a resource. Event pattern helps you filter those real-time requests. So using Event oattern your lambda would be triggered everytime there was an event that matched. Scheduled expression is used to periodically trigger something. It's not event driven. It will just trigger the lambda at set times.

Comment: In our case we want multiple event to schedule so based on that event we want to map that into our lambda and push the task related to that into MQ. we just need event to be passed on specific time to lambda

thats the ref thing i want to achieve
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956840/setting-up-event-pattern-in-cloud-watch-event-rule)

Comment: That's not how event bridge works. From the aws docs `A rule can run in response to an event, or at certain time intervals`. It's one or the other. I still didn't get your use case. Do you want to collect all the events that matched a specific pattern but only process all those events at the same time using a schedule ?

Comment: Yeah i know that aws doc case thats why i am passing input into aws_cloudwatch_event_target ones now that previous link i shared mentioned in case if we want to send some data with scheduled event also but the thing is terraform infra setup correctly but didnt get that input in lambda handler

Comment: ISSUE SOLVED: 
basically, i was using the previous AwsLogEvent type in go lambda instead i should use an interface{} type instead as I override input into aws_cloudwatch_event_target in terraform. Now I am getting that input in the console log.